# How can I make nginx use my certificate?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, https

I need to configure a reverse-proxy on nginx that allows https.
The way it's supposed to work is the following:

1. Client connects to the site (port 80);
2. The reverse-proxy redirects it to port 443;
3. The communication is encrypted using my certificate;
4. The client request is then proxy_pass'ed to another site.

My problem is in 3 and 4. My configuration successfully does all this and redirects to the site that it's supposed to, but instead of using my certificate it uses the certificate of the site that I'm redirecting to.

Configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name:443;
} 

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.key;

    location {
        proxy_pass https://another-site.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Like I said, this works but it doesn't use the certificate I specified in this configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you must put more configs inside it

like

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name example.com;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.key;
keepalive_timeout    50;
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES;  #Check ciphers at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_ciphers
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams_4096.pem; check dhparams at nginx documentation  
ssl_session_cache shared:ssl_session_cache:20m;
```

}

Comment: I can't fully explain it, but basically with only the necessary ssl configurations I was able to proxy pass to other sites, even if they themselves had certificates, and it would use my certificate, except for that one site mentioned. I think this has to do with the configuration (it's also nginx). I've got it working now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. 
The configuration is correct and it works, the problem is that the site to which I'm redirecting the traffic is also wrapping the traffic with their own certificate, hence why it looks like I'm not using my own.
I figured this out by trying to redirect the traffic to another website